# MS Excel Payback Period Formula to Display Year / Compare Cumulative Totals in Separate Rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, vlookup

I am working on a project that is supposed to compare the cost of automation vs non-automated call analyzing and then tell you what year the payback period will be. I am having issues trying to get the formula right to just display the year when the cost of the automated system is less than the cost of the non-automated system. I have tried using LOOKUP, but can't seem to figure out the logic I guess to get it to display the right year. All formulas must us cell references.  Here is my data:

```
`First row:                 Year:   1    2    3    4    5    6     7`
`Second row:  Cumulative Total 1: $15  $25  $55  $60  $75  $85  $100`
`Third row:   Cumulative Total 2:  $5  $10  $15  $50  $80  $95  $200`
`Fourth row: Payback Period Year:` 5
```

The top row displays a seven year analysis of the cost of two systems, automated, and non-automated. The second row is an example of total spent per year of the automated system, and the third row is the total spent on the non-automated system. These are cumulative totals. Once the total cost in the second row becomes less then the cost in the third row in the same year, then the cell in the fourth row after "Payback Period Year:" should display the correct year number from the top row. Any help with this would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm it doesn't seem that a `VLOOKUP` will work here.

Assuming that the year 1 is in column B, you can put this in cell B4:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(C2:I2>C3:I3,1,0))+1
```

Do NOT hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Instead, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> because the formula is calculating the sum of an array.

What the formula does is it vertically compares each value in the arrays:

```
15 25 55 60 75 85 100
 5 10 15 50 80 95 200
```

And returns

```
 1  1  1  1  0  0   0
```

Meaning the first instance is true (15 > 5) hence `1`, the second as well (25 > 10), etc, until it hits (75 > 80) which is false and starts returning `0`.

`SUMPRODUCT` adds the numbers, giving 4 and we add 1 to give the 5th year.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I probably wouldn't have figured this out because I have never even used the SUMPRODUCT function and I didn't know that you had to use Ctrl+Shirt+Enter to calculate arrays.  I learned a lot in this one question. Much appreciated!

Comment: @CharlWillia6 You're welcome! You can also hit F9 to see actual arrays, but then, the cell will display the array instead of the final value and you will lose the formula. Viewing the array is useful when you work with those :)